# Bad IL Format when loading exe in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I have two .NET Core 3.0 WPF projects. One of them, I published into an executable called "DefaultPlugin.exe".

In my second WPF project, I'm trying to load the first project using Assembly.Load and read the types. However, when I do so, I get an exception, "Bad IL Format" from System.Private.CoreLib. It works when I load the DefaultPlugin.dll from the bin folder I also checked my CPU configuration to make sure they match.

```
///Works:
string path = @"C:\Users\S-D81\source\repos\DefaultPlugin\DefaultPlugin\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\win-x64\DefaultPlugin.dll";
///Does not work:
//string path = @"C:\Users\S-D81\source\repos\DefaultPlugin\DefaultPlugin\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\win-x64\DefaultPlugin.exe";
//string path = @"C:\Users\S-D81\source\repos\DefaultPlugin\DefaultPlugin\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\win-x64\publish\DefaultPlugin.exe";

Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
```

Is there a way to use Assembly.Load on a published .NET Core 3.0 assembly or is this just a limitation of the new framework?

Comment: How are you publishing your project? There are a number of different publishing modes

Comment: It's publishing as a single file, trimmed, with release configuration, targeting x64. But even when I simply try to load the .exe from the bin/Debug folder, it gives the same error.

Comment: If it's being published as a single (trimmed) file called "DefaultPlugin.exe", how are you then able to Assembly.Load a file called "DefaultPlugin.dll"? Also if it's a release build, why is it in a Debug folder?

Comment: I'm just trying to use Assembly.Load on any of the built assemblies to see which ones will work. It looks like the .exe file is consistently not loading regardless of how it is built, whether it's in the debug, release, or published folder. This just tells me that .net core might have an issue reading any .exe regardless of how it is built. My question is probably framed badly, but in the end I will need to read the executable solely from the published version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The generated .exe file in .NET Core 3.0 applications is not an IL assembly but a native host executable that finds and boots the runtime before loading the actual IL application assembly which has a .dll extension.

You should be able to load your plugin by loading the .dll file next to the .exe file with the same project name.

Comment: Is there any way to load or reference that dll after the project has been published into a self contained executable?

Comment: You mean as in single-file publish? that doesn't work since single-file publish is a native bundle that extracts embedded files into a temporary directory and then executes them.

Comment: Aw I was worried that was the case. Thank you.

Comment: simple - use the dll rather than exe file.
You'd think it would give you a better error message in that case.