# Load and execute .NET Application from memory

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, .net-assembly

I have a .NET 5 application, that references several other projects and also some native libraries. I need to encrypt this application, load this encrypted file into memory, decrypt it and execute it from another .NET application.

My approach was to publish the target app as a single file and then encrypt this file. Then I load it, decrypt it and try to run it like this :

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load(libraryBytes);
MethodInfo methodInfo = assembly.EntryPoint;
methodInfo.Invoke(null, null);
```

This fails with "Bad IL Format" exception. It is because the published single file [is not IL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290286/bad-il-format-when-loading-exe-in-net-core-3-0).
Is there some other way I can load my app from drive, decrypt it and execute it ? I have an important constraint : **decrypted binary must never be stored to file**

Comment: Why is your constraint a constraint?  Your binary must contain your password, to decode the target app (unless you are going to ask the user for a password each time), so it's still not bullet-proof.

Comment: the password is not stored in the binary,nor anywhere else on the drive. Bullet-proofing was not the design goal

Comment: Is there anything that would prevent you from for example zip them together in a single file that you can decrypt and load each assembly by itself?

Comment: What is the actual goal? What difference does it make if it is stored in memory or in a file? regular users would not know what to do with an assembly anyway, and it would not prevent access for a sufficiently skilled user, so who are you protecting against?

Comment: If bullet-proofing isn't the design goal, what's the point of going through any of this unnecessary pain at all?

Comment: @Akade Yes, I am considering this. However, i am not sure how to load native asseblies and if they all register correctly