# Runtime error with a very basic reflection example in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, runtime-error, assemblies

I'm trying to learn a bit more about `System.Reflection` using the official microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/viewing-type-information). Specifically I'm trying to run the following example:

```
// Loads an assembly using its file name.
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyExe.exe");
// Gets the type names from the assembly.
Type[] types2 = a.GetTypes();
foreach (Type t in types2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.FullName);
}
```

So I made a new console app using `dotnet new console -o=customconsole`. I then removed `ImplicitUsings` from my project file (because I don't like that), and came up with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace get_type_from_assembly 
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // load assembly using full file name
            Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\\Users\\bobmarley\\desktop\\temp\\csharp-reflection\\get-type-from-assembly\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\console-custom.exe");
            // get type names from assembly
            Type[] types2 = a.GetTypes();
            foreach (Type t in types2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t.FullName);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to run the generated executable using  `dotnet run --project=customconsole`. I got the following runtime error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Bad IL format. The format of the file 'C:\Users\bobmarley\desktop\temp\csharp-reflection\get-type-from-assembly\bin\Debug\net6.0\console-custom.exe' is invalid.
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromPath(IntPtr ptrNativeAssemblyLoadContext, String ilPath, String niPath, ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(String assemblyPath)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at get_type_from_assembly.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\bobmarley\desktop\temp\csharp-reflection\get-type-from-assembly\Program.cs:line 11
make: *** [Makefile:5: run] Error 1
```

I'm not sure why this occurs, because I checked and the executable does exist in the specified path. What is happening here and how can I fix it?

Comment: "the executable does exist in the specified path" - well yes - the exception doesn't say otherwise. It says it's a "bad IL format". Have you tried loading that executable in ildasm or a similar tool? Is there a DLL alongside the .exe file? If so, try loading that instead...

Comment: Plenty of explanations on the docs page for [System.BadImageFormatException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bad IL Format when loading exe in .NET Core 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290286/bad-il-format-when-loading-exe-in-net-core-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

A likely reason is that the your project and the loaded assembly target different platforms, i.e. x86 vs x64, In my experience that is a common reason for `BadImageFormatException`. Another possible reasons is that one targets .net core while the other targets .net framework.

Dynamically loading an assembly will require that it is compatible with your project. If you want to read arbitrary assemblies you probably want some tool that can extract whatever information you are after from the CIL code directly, without actually loading it.